# collection as association

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

I'm looking for the tool that can build class diagram form the code and shows the fact that "class A contains field 'Items' that is generic collection of B" as specific association from class A to B?

Current class diagram not visualize this reference.

I'm also wondered what is strange in this my request, since I have tried several VS plugins (and VS Ultimate) and no one do such simple thing. As I remember 10 years ago JTogether did this for Java code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the class diagram in Visual Studio, you can right-click a collection property and choose "Show as (Collection) Association".

Comment: shame on me. was searching for it in class diagram menu